# Advanced Excel Formula Has Me Stumped

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know basic formulas in Excel, and can navigate through some more difficult ones too. But nothing is working for me on the one I am trying to create now. Can anyone advise me on how to create a formula that does this;

h13 is the cell where you enter sq ft.....
h3 is the cell that calculates hours based on sq ft entered in h13

43,560 sq ft equals 1 hour of time.

I need cell h3 to calculate time based on the sq ft entered in cell h13 using the rule that 43,560 sq ft equal 1 hour.

Thank you in advance for assistance.

Comment: How many hours for 43,561 sq. ft.?

Comment: Basic formula ```=H13/43560``` not working?

Comment: I guess that is my bigger issue. I have confused myself to the point where I am unable to figure out the correlating time to each square foot.

Comment: No the basic formula =h13/43560 does not work because its not calculating the answer into a time.

Comment: try `=h13/43560/24` You need to convert `1` which is typically a day into `1` hour.

Comment: I appreciate the help! That equation doesn't work either unfortunately. I need to find out how much time it takes per sq ft based on 43,560 sq ft takes one hour. That way the user can enter any square footage and the correct allotted time will calculate.

Comment: Basic... I think maybe I am overthinking it and that will work, rather it coverts to time. Pricing is working, so I think i am just over thinking. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: This is not an Excel question. This is an algebra question. Set up the equation and solve for _x_.

Comment: @Michelle,, are U trying to calculate that if `43560` = `1 hrs` then what would be the `Hrs` for `80500`, like this ?

Comment: Yes that is correct,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

43560 sqft in  1 hour ie. 60 min
1sq ft. In.       60/43560 min

The formula in minutes will be

```
=(60/43560)*H13
```

Eg Answer will be in minutes

Now convert to hours

```
=((60/43560)*H13)/60
```

Eg Result may be 345.4677  which is hours

If you don't need minutes  and get up approx with hours

```
= INT(((60/43560)*H13)/60)
```

Eg Result in integer value of 345 hours

If you want to calculate  in  hours and minutes

```
= (INT(((60/43560)*H13)/60)) & " Hours, " &  (MOD(((60/43560)*H13),60)) &" minutes "
```

Eg Result will be  345 Hours and  46 minutes

If u need in days hours minutes seconds do tell me i have to test it first

The formula given is not tested as I had formatted my laptop today may have some errors in brackets do tell me if it has some problem and you have any more queries feel free to ask it

Comment: @Michelle if you need numeric value then try =((60/43560)*H13)/60 formula it will result 345.8934 hours in  decimal numeric  but it's approx value minutes not converted rest minutes and hours  I have test and write it I will install my laptop today will try to  find exact tested formula soon and let you know

Comment: @rajesh thanx buddy again i think michelle needs numeric value in was in  minutes and hours that is 32 houra 42 min (32.42 is what michalle require) what we have to do is find hours  and min combine them in text and then convert to numeric through formula for that I have try and in android mobile could not work with excel

Comment: Thank you all for your help!